# Webstorm 10 says "expected close }}" on Angularjs template code

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

I am using WebStorm 10.0.4 with some Angularjs files and it seems to mostly work. But, WebStorm incorrectly flags some correct {{code}}. Specifically, in this example:

```
<div>{{thisworks}}</div>
<div>{{butnotthis | uppercase}}</div>
<div>{{oreventhis()}}</div>
```

The first line is OK, but WebStorm marks the second and third lines as incorrect (squiggly red line). The error message it gives is "expected close }}" for each line, as you can see:

[image: error]

Under Preferences->Javascript->libraries I have

- angularjs-DefinetlyTyped (from Download->Typescript Community stubs)
- HTML
- HTML5 / ECMASCRIPT 5
- Meteor project library (this is a meteor project)
- Node.js globals

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Meteor projects, WebStorm treats .html files as spacebar templates by default, so these Angular injections are parsed as handlebars ones. Please disable 'Open html files as handlebars' in the settings 'File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Templates - does this help? Note that Angular support in Meteor projects is planned for WebStorm 11 ([WEB-17118](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17118))

Answer (score 0):

Please try [WebStorm 11 EAP](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/08/webstorm-11-eap-142-4148/) it has complete support for the Meteor-Angular package (you don't need to disable the 'Templates->Open html as handlebars' option)

Comment: I have Webstorm 11.0.3, but still have this problem. Has the fix not been released in the definite Webstorm 11 release?

Comment: @Martijn possible you need to disable 'File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Templates' -> Open html as handlebars

Comment: Same problem still exists. any updates or solutions on how to fix this.